# Discord botを動かすとselect menuを選択した後にAttributeErrorが出てinteractionエラーになる

Tags: python, discord

チケットシステムについてです。
id エラーの解除方法がわかりません。
select menu　選択まではdiscordで正常に動作します。
select menuを選択した後に下記のエラーが出てinteractionエラーが発生します。
エラーを改善し、カテゴリー内にチャンネルを作成するにはどうしたら良いか。
詳しい方教えてください。

エラーコード

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/runner/tiket/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/ui/view.py", line 427, in _scheduled_task
    await item.callback(interaction)
  File "main.py", line 29, in my_callback
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket",category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
  File "/home/runner/tiket/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1369, in create_text_channel
    data = await self._create_channel(
  File "/home/runner/tiket/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/guild.py", line 1227, in _create_channel
    payload = {'allow': allow.value, 'deny': deny.value, 'id': target.id}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

```
import discord
from discord.ui import Button, View,Select
from discord.ext import commands


token = ""

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=discord.Intents.all())

async def ticketcallback(interaction):
  guild = interaction.guild
  role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="MODERATER")
  overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = False),
    interaction.user: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True),
    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(view_channel = True)
  }
  
  select = Select(options=[
    discord.SelectOption(label="Help ticket",value="01",emoji="✅",description="Open a Help ticket"),
    discord.SelectOption(label="Other ticket",value="02",emoji="❌",description="Open a tiket in other section")
  ])


  
  async def my_callback(interaction):
    if select.values[0] == "01":
      category = guild.get_channel(guild.categories, name="tickets")
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket",category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"created tiket - <#{channel.ID}",ephemeral=True)
      await channel.send("Help?")
    elif select.values[0] == "02":
      category = discord.utils.get(guild.categories, name="Other tikets")
      channel = await guild.create_text_channel(f"{interaction.user.name}-ticket",category=category, overwrites=overwrites)
      await interaction.response.send_message(f"created tiket - <#{channel.ID}",ephemeral=True)
      await channel.send("Help?")

  select.callback = my_callback
  view = View(timeout = None)
  view.add_item(select)
  await interaction.response.send_message("Option bloe",view=view, ephemeral=True)

@bot.command()
async def ticket(ctx):
  button = Button(label="チケット作成",style=discord.ButtonStyle.green)
  button.callback = ticketcallback
  view = View(timeout=None)
  view.add_item(button)
  await ctx.send("Open ticket",view=view)

bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

利用されている discord.py の正確なバージョンが分かりませんが、エラーが出ていると思われる個所のコード https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/270fa5f2e0d7eca396f9df0bcc9ad0e643c2fe9a/discord/guild.py#L1229-L1234 を読む限り、`overwrites` がうまく設定できていません。`target`、つまり `overwrites` のキー側のどれかが `None` になっています。

今回のコードだと一番怪しそうなのは `role` で、`discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="MODERATER")` がきちんと意味のある値を返せているかどうかをチェックしてみてください。